# Can't Resume from Suspend in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lts, hp-pavilion

Hi Everyone first thing is that i got a problem when i suspend the PC, it suspends like a normal PC but when i try to resume that's when i get the problem.... i can't resume, the PC turns ON but in the screen theres no signal only blackscreen here my PC specs.

PC specs:
Video Card:AMD Radeon HD 6480M Discrete-Class
RAM: DDR3 de 4 GB
Microprocessor: 2.5 Ghz VISION A4 Technology from AMD with AMD Dual-Core A4-3310MX Accelerated Processor
Display: 35,5 cm (14,0") High-Definition LED HP BrightView Display (1366 x 768)
Hard Drive: 500 GB SATA (5400 rpm)

If need more specs, please advise me.
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02901644&cc=us&destPage=document&lc=en&product=5113863&tmp_docname=c02905502

PS: i know, i saw other posts but i was unsure if those methods were going to work in Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64Bit

Comment: In some HP laptops, the brightness seems to go to zero during a wake up or login. Try entering your password on the blank screen, press enter and try increasing brightness with keyboard keys. It might work.

Comment: @VibhavSinha I will try it, and i open this post because usually my Compiz and Unity or desktop environment got damaged (actually i restaured unity and the compiz and now everything is working fine). and sorry for the bad english :P i do my best.